# How could I display the last modified date/time in the backend of the product?

Tags: magento2.2.6

I would like to display when a product was last modified on the backend of a item page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

- To get Product updated time, from item page(Supposed it should be product page), try:

```
$product->getUpdatedAt()
```

- To format the date you could inherit a function to a extended block or call in a helper.

```
/**
     * Retrieve formatting date
     *
     * @param null|string|\DateTimeInterface $date
     * @param int $format
     * @param bool $showTime
     * @param null|string $timezone
     * @return string
     */
    public function formatDate(
        $date = null,
        $format = \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
        $showTime = false,
        $timezone = null
    ) {
        $date = $date instanceof \DateTimeInterface ? $date : new \DateTime($date);
        return $this->_localeDate->formatDateTime(
            $date,
            $format,
            $showTime ? $format : \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
            null,
            $timezone
        );
    }
```

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($product->getUpdatedAt()) ?>
```

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->formatDate($product->getUpdatedAt()) ?>
```

Comment: I have never done anything in the adminhtml area before. I tried to place the file in Magento_Theme/view/adminhtml/templates/title.phtml. I was thinking next to the header I could just add the date next to the title. It isn't pulling the correct template. What would you suggest?